# Seagate hard drive, logic board fried. Desperately need replacement

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

As a Christmas present to my grandparents I was going to backup their data, format their hard drive and reinstall the OS so their computer ran better. A few minutes after started to work on it the logic board on the outside of the hard drive bit the dust ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIWUB.jpg)). It looks replaceable if I can just find another logic board that will fit on the drive. The drive is question is a Seagate Barracuda 7200.9, 320 GB 3.5" SATA drive (model # ST3320833AS). Does anyone have this exact drive that they would want to sell? Or know of a place where I could get this drive or Seagate replacement parts? Please, I need to get this drive back up and working because I didn't get a chance to back up any of their data. They'd be crushed if I lost it.

Full album of pictures for the drive: http://imgur.com/a/02hwf/seagate__fried_outside_circuit_board

Comment: All images in this question are broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go on Ebay and get one that is identical. I've done it before successfully. I don't remember what brand but I'm pretty sure it was WD or Maxtor.

Comment: Same, I've had to get replacement drives of ebay for this. Our data recovery guy never throws out a HDD - he's got a shelf with hundreds of them, but still not very good odds of having the right one..

Comment: I found the same exact model on eBay and was able to swap the PCB boards and get data off the drive. I can't comment if this is a longer term solution because I haven't used the drive since I pulled the data off.

Answer (score 1):

These are suppliers of those HDD pcb boards, they can properly match up one for you.

http://www.hdd-parts.com/

http://www.onepcbsolution.com/

http://www.hddzone.com/

.

How to match a pcb board

http://www.harddrive-repair.com/hard-drive-parts.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a 50/50 operation, really. Ask for pictures before purchasing anything, **it is critical to ensure that the replacement board *really is identical***. My record is 1 for 3 and that's only because I had 3 identical unused spares lying around.

To note about logic boards, taken from [here](http://www.hddrecovery.com.au/PDF/200ways.pdf):

> If a PCB swap does not work then the most common problem is that the match was not close
>   enough. In any production run of a particular model of hard drive there could be as many as
>   several dozen changes in firmware upgrades, components on the board, etc.
>
> To have the best possible chance all of the code numbers and letters on the top plate of your
>   drive and its parts donor should be the same. If you have no success then find a reliable data
>   recovery firm near you as you has done as much as you can.

Answer (score -1):

If the failure was 100% logic board then yes it has a fair chance.
On most *new* drives ie more recent than maybe mid 2007 they use an 8 pin Flash IC which fails almost as often due to radiation damage over time.
The data recovery companies might be your best bet as they can identify (by swapping to near identical drive) what has occured and thus reduce the chances of making things worse.

Comment: Fails due to radiation damage?  Where do you get the stuff you put in your answers?